# Sort 2D array on a column with duplicates moving duplicates to top JavaScript / Google Script

Tags: javascript, sorting, google-apps-script, multidimensional-array

I need to sort a 2D array on a column with duplicates, moving duplicates to the top.

I can sort a 2D array in descending order with:

```
values.sort((a, b) => a[2].localeCompare(b[2]));
```

But how do you move duplicates to the top, keeping their sorted order?

Have

```
X1  Z9  fake8@fake.com.sn
X3  Z7  fake7@fake.com
X4  Z6  fake6@fake.com
X5  Z1  fake1@fake.com
X5  Z7  fake7@fake.com
X7  Z2  fake5@fake.com
X8  Z6  fake6@fake.com
X9  Z5  fake5@fake.com
X9  Z8  fake8@fake.com
```

After sorting:

```
X5  Z1  fake1@fake.com
X7  Z2  fake5@fake.com
X9  Z5  fake5@fake.com
X4  Z6  fake6@fake.com
X8  Z6  fake6@fake.com
X3  Z7  fake7@fake.com
X5  Z7  fake7@fake.com
X9  Z8  fake8@fake.com
X1  Z9  fake8@fake.com.sn
```

Need

```
X7  Z2  fake5@fake.com
X9  Z5  fake5@fake.com
X4  Z6  fake6@fake.com
X8  Z6  fake6@fake.com
X3  Z7  fake7@fake.com
X5  Z7  fake7@fake.com
X5  Z1  fake1@fake.com
X9  Z8  fake8@fake.com
X1  Z9  fake8@fake.com.sn
```

Comment: You can create another key (one you don't show) that flags rows as duplicates. Then your sort can take that key into account as the primary sort key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Workaround:

The way I approached this is to extract the last column of the 2d array, sort it according to your preferred output, then sort the 2d array based on that column.

Try this code snippet:

```js
var values = [['X1', 'Z9', 'fake8@fake.com.sn'],
['X3', 'Z7', 'fake7@fake.com'],
['X4', 'Z6', 'fake6@fake.com'],
['X5', 'Z1', 'fake1@fake.com'],
['X5', 'Z7', 'fake7@fake.com'],
['X7', 'Z2', 'fake5@fake.com'],
['X8', 'Z6', 'fake6@fake.com'],
['X9', 'Z5', 'fake5@fake.com'],
['X9', 'Z8', 'fake8@fake.com']];

//Extracts the the last column of the array
var lastCol = values.map(a => a[2])

//Extracts the duplicate elements of the last column
var dup = lastCol.filter(a => lastCol.indexOf(a) != lastCol.lastIndexOf(a)).sort()

//Extracts the unique elements of the last column
var unique = lastCol.filter(a => lastCol.indexOf(a) == lastCol.lastIndexOf(a)).sort()

//combines the duplicate and unique elements, sorted to the preferred output.
var sortOrder = dup.concat(unique);

//sorts the 2d array based on sorted last column
var sortedArray = values.sort((a, b) => sortOrder.indexOf(a[2]) - sortOrder.indexOf(b[2]))

console.log(sortedArray)
```

### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: You should use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to show your code working in-browser, rather than showing an image of the executed code, which is of limited use to people with different visual abilities and search engines, which don't index images of text.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation, Heretic Monkey. I've modified the answer and included a code snippet.

Comment: I was trying to get something that worked using Pointy's comment above but not getting anything as nice as this!!  Thank you